# How to call redux action from a clickHandler passed to a functional component as prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to call a redux action from the onClickHandler function which is passed to a functional component as props but nothing happens.

I'm passing the clickHandler as a prop to the child Component and handling it in the ParentComponent as Child Component is a functional component.

**Code for ParentComponent**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect,store } from 'react-redux';
// import statement for component
// import statement for redux actions

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  clickHandler(data){
   // call this.props.actions(data) here;
  }

  renderList(){
        return <ChildComponent 
          key={field.name}
          clickHandler={() => this.clickHandler(field.name)}
          />
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, {
   actions
 })(ParentComponent);
```

**Code for ChildComponent**

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return(    
    <span onClick={props.clickHandler} className="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The issue was I had same action creator in another file which was getting called. Changing the name of the action creator to something unique solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to pass the props to the child component and the child component onClick will pass the arguments to the function

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect,store } from 'react-redux';
// import statement for component
// import statement for redux actions

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  clickHandler(data){
   // call this.props.actions(data) here;
  }

  renderList(){
        return <ChildComponent 
          key={field.name}
          name={field.name}
          clickHandler={this.clickHandler}
          />
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, {
   actions
 })(ParentComponent);
```

**Child Component**

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return(    
    <span onClick={()=> props.clickHandler(props.name)} className="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
  )
}
```

Comment: But this will fire the onClick event during rendering of the component as well.

Comment: I have edited the answer, this is one way of doing it, another way would be to write a separate function inside the component which will fire the function received through props with props.name